# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code snippet but i got warning. How can avoid this.
I search this problem but couldnt find any to solve mine.

And here is the code that gets warning, (df_test_arima is pandas dataframe)

```
df_test_arima['ACTUAL'] = y_test
```

y_test is from ;

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X.index,y, shuffle = False, test_size=0.050)
```

Warning that i got

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: How can i use this? I saw this question. Same warning but not the use of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `loc` (to copy all corresponding rows, cols)

```
df_test_arima['ACTUAL'] = y_test.loc[:,:]
```

Another way is to disable all such warning in your file (not recommended though)

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=SettingWithCopyWarning)
```

Comment: Thank you Pawan, the first way is not working, i still get the same error.